# Wrong if/else statement? There is no data on db but it is getting value?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write basic friendship script. But there is a problem. While there is no data on my database table it is accepting `is_approved` column = 0

while there is no data on my MySQL database , it prints "`request pending`" why?

**EDIT**

```
$per = $db->query("SELECT * FROM permission WHERE user_id = " . $profile_owner_id . "");
$per->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$per_dat = $per->fetch(); //


//FETCH friendship table // THERE IS NO DATA in friendship table 
$friend_request = $db->query("SELECT * FROM friendship WHERE sender_id = ".$_SESSION['SES_USER_ID']." AND receiver_id=".$profile_owner_id."");
$friend_request->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$fr_data = $friend_request->fetch(); //



if ( $_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] != $profile_owner_id ) {

        if($per_dat["get_friendship_request"] == 1) {
            if($fr_data["is_approved"] ==1){
               echo "Allready friend";
            }

            else if($fr_data["is_approved"]==0){
               echo "request pending";
            }

            else{
                echo "Send friend request.";
            }
        }

        else{
            echo "He/she does not accept friend requests..";
        }
```

Comment: where is `$fr_data` and `$per_dat` declared?

Comment: Please `var_dump($fr_data["is_approved"]);` and explain, where this variable is retrieved from.

Comment: `"it prints "request pending" why?"` - Because `$_SESSION["SES_USER_ID"] != $profile_owner_id` and `$per_dat["get_friendship_request"] == 1` and `$fr_data["is_approved"] == 0`, clearly.  Where/how you get those values isn't shown, though, so we can't really advise on that.

Comment: var_dump($fr_data["is_approved"]); prints ->>> NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in php a variable is unset,

```
$fr_data["is_approved"]==0
```

evaluates to true.  You can use the triple equal operator to avoid this behaviour.

```
$fr_data["is_approved"]===0
```

A thorough explanation can be found [in this blog](http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/10/31/triple-equal-operator-and-null-in-php/), the short version is that value-wise (ie, the regular == test) 0, NULL, 0.0 are all the same for php.  The triple equality operator checks value ***and*** type so it will only evaluate to true if 0 is the actual content of the variable.

Comment: Great!  Good luck with your project!